# inner join two tables having null values on the foreign keys of each other

Tags: mysql, sql, null, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have the following data in the database in table1

[image]

I run the following query and returns nothing

```
SELECT
  someColumns

  FROM table1

  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
  INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.anotherId = table3.anotherId
```

I want to return all the records in (table2 with id = table1.id and table3 with anotherId = table1.anotherId)

Comment: you should read up on the difference between INNER and OUTER joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get the specified result.